# Storing millions of 100kb PDFs in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a software that checks every factory machine and produces PDF output around 100kb. This is a scheduled task for 12 hours. I have more than 18.000 machines and with the new factories it will increase. Roughly I got million records of PDF documents in a month. I also need to show them to end user with filter option incase of any problems in machines.

I'm using C# ASP.NET in the back-end and SQL Server 2014.

What would be the efficent way to store them? Directly in DB with nvarbinary(max) or with a file system?

I was going to use file server but this [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/to-blob-or-not-to-blob-large-object-storage-in-a-database-or-a-filesystem/) made me confused, so I wanted to ask.

-Edit-

After discussing with my manager, we have decided to use following approach. Thanks everyone with their helpful comments, you contributed a lot.

We will store the data in a meaningful table structure with text format. When end user want to have PDF, we will create the PDF and serve it just in time. not gonna store them. We will also use S3 CDN for the images in the PDF and will save their metadata in DB.

When new report required, developer will get the template from db first, will implement the details with reporting editör, then will send this xml script along with the user parameters (language, authority etc) to our SOA (service oriented architecture) based mechanism. Our SOA engine will evaluate the request, fill the xml script with correct data & language, render, then will send back to user.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filestream-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#when-to-use-filestream

Comment: Looking into FILESTREAM in SQL server is probably a good idea

Comment: Do **not** store files as `nvarchar(max)`. Potentially `varbinary(max)` with `FILESTREAM` enabled, but frankly: this screams "file system"

Comment: Another vote for FILESTREAM

Comment: I'd prefer Azure Storage with metadata in your database.

Comment: Also consider [File Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filetables-sql-server), which is built on FILESTREAM.

Comment: As some above - store them as files on the HD.  Windows already indexes files so let it do what it already does, otherwise you're just converting a file to something in order to store it in another file with a second layer of indexing.  Use the file system with sensible folder and file names.

Comment: What is "with a filter"? Searching the *contents* of the PDF? PDF's for a certain machine(s)? Time period? Other data?

Comment: Thank you guys for all the comments. Filters are machineID, createUser and time period. Would you recommend storing them in Azure or using the FILESTREAM then?

Comment: If you're going to use Azure, you can use their blob storage containers which is actually designed to store documents / files etc, infact if you're using Azure, don't bother with file system at all, use the blob storage containers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the PDFs you are writing to are mostly the same, you could store the variables into a database. Then, when somebody requests a report, or whatever it is, you pull the PDF template file and fill it with the appropriate values retrieved from the database.

Comment: Agreed. On demand PDF with the underlying data in a database seems more useful, especially if you ever want to programmatically process the contents, as trying to pull data out of a pre-made PDF will have it's own challenges.

Comment: Yes they are mostly same, they gone through some checks like is it working or not, how long it was operating etc. I'm planning to generalize them as a template and use the templates for PDF creation, but each machine must have a PDF for that time.

Comment: This requirement (_each machine must have a PDF for that time_) seems very odd and, in my opinion puts you on the bad course. Why creating millions of PDF and leave them around for nothing? Your managers will never be able in their entire life to look at all those files. Store in the db the data you want to put in the PDF and when required build the PDF on the fly with that data

Answer (score 1):

> I have a software that checks every factory machine and produces PDF output around 100kb.

You have two options, first is instead of producing PDFs as output, produce text as you can store text more efficiently than a PDF.

I'm going to take a guess and say it might be a little too late for that based on you saying that you already have 18,000 factories, in which case store the pdf on the file system and store its location in the database.

Comment: Well this project runs on several factories and they have over 18k machines in total. But I will deliver a new architecture with the PDFs so you might consider this project as a new. 

Are you suggesting that I should store the output as text and when user wants to see, just create a PDF?

Comment: That's right, I think it's a bad idea to bloat a relational database with actual files as its not exactly designed for that use case. You would be better off just creating the PDF on demand

Answer (score 1):

As you working with lots of data so, don't use PDF files to store in database, instead use table structured data as SQL DB is designed for, and use the PDF variable templets if you have similar kind of data structure in your PDF files.

Your sequence is:  Process(may be also include DB) > PDF > DB

It should be:      Process > DB  > PDF

And also if your file have some geometrical and graphical data also, then describe your question in more detail with a sample file so that we will help for that also.